# PHPExcel add new row after looping rows mysql

Tags: php, phpexcel

hello all i have created microsoft excel file that shows all data from mysql with foreach, the problem is how can i add new row exactly below of my looping colums? thanks.

this is my codes

```
foreach($anggota as $data)
      $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$numrow, $no);
      $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$numrow, $data->tgl_daftar);
      $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$numrow, $data->kd_anggota);
      $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D'.$numrow, $data->nm_anggota);
      $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E'.$numrow, $data->nm_dinas);
      $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F'.$numrow, $data->nm_simpanan);
      $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G'.$numrow, $data->nominal_simpanan);
      $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H'.$numrow, $data->keterangan);


      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$numrow)->applyFromArray($style_row_center);
      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$numrow)->applyFromArray($style_row_center);
      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C'.$numrow)->applyFromArray($style_row_center);
      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D'.$numrow)->applyFromArray($style_row);
      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E'.$numrow)->applyFromArray($style_row);
      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F'.$numrow)->applyFromArray($style_row);
      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('G'.$numrow)->applyFromArray($style_row);
      $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$numrow)->applyFromArray($style_row);

      $no++;
      $numrow++;
    }

//here i want to add new row but i don't know how many rows result created by the looping...
```

Comment: FYI:  PHPExcel last version, 1.8.1, was released in 2015. The project is no longer maintained and should not be used anymore. Use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet instead

Comment: Also, to know how many rows were created, create a `$counter` variable before the `foreach()`, then put it in the foreach with `$counter++` just like your other variables and outside of the foreach it will contain a number of how many loops were ran